# Why doesn't my external Java file get compiled by the main program, when it imports a class that I've built, even if it's in the same package?

Tags: java, compilation, exec

I'm building a program that needs to compile a Java file saved in an external package and execute it. The issue that I'm having is that the external file needs to import a class that I've built, but whenever I specify the import at the beginning of the code, the main class doesn't compile the external Java file.
However, if I remove the import from the external file, it compiles without issues.

This is the code:

**Main class**

```
package zhrfrd.jrobots;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class JRobots {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Compile and execute external java program
        try {
            Process processCompilation = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac -d /Users/faridzouheir/eclipse-workspace/JRobots/src/ /Users/faridzouheir/eclipse-workspace/JRobots/src/zhrfrd/testjrobots/Test.java");   // Compile Test.java
            processCompilation.waitFor();   // Wait until the process is terminated before starting the following process (to avoid the second process not working properly)
            Process processExecution = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp /Users/faridzouheir/eclipse-workspace/JRobots/src/ zhrfrd.testjrobots.Test");   // Execute java (-cp is class path)
            
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processExecution.getInputStream()));   // Get result of the execution of the external file
            String line = null;
            
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) { 
                System.out.println(line); 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Execution error.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Interrupted exception.");
        }
    }
}
```

**External file to be executed (Test)**

```
package zhrfrd.testjrobots;

import java.io.IOException;

import zhrfrd.jrobots.Robot;   //This is the import that doesn't allow the compilation

public class Test{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static Robot rob;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         Robot rob;
        int a = 300;
        int b = 23;
        int res = doSum(a, b);
        System.out.println(res);
//         boom();
        rob = new Robot();
        rob.boom();
    }

    public static int doSum(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

**Robot class**

```
package zhrfrd.jrobots;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Robot extends JLabel implements Runnable{
    protected static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected int life, direction, speed, posX, posY;
    protected Thread threadRobot;
    private Random random;
    private Dimension size;

    // Constructor
    public Robot() throws IOException {
        this.life = 100;
        threadRobot = new Thread(this, "My thread");
    }
    
    // Methods
    //Set robot position
    public void setPosition() {
        random = new Random();
        posX = random.nextInt(500);
        posY = random.nextInt(500);
        size = this.getPreferredSize();
        this.setBounds(posX, posY, size.width, size.height);
        
        System.out.println(posX);
    }
    
    //TEST METHOD
    public void boom() {
        System.out.println("BOOM BOOM!!");
    }

    @Override
    public void run () {
        System.out.println(threadRobot.getName());
        setPosition();
        
    }
}
```

Note: I tried to move the Robot class inside the same package of the Test file but it still doesn't work. Also, in case I want to remove the main method from the Test file and make it as a subclass of Robot, is it still possible to compile it and execute it.

Comment: `the main class doesn't compile the external Java file.` You should include the error message of the compiler, but my guess is that you didn't compile the `Robot` file. Also, its .class file must be on the compile classpath, and in a directory corresponding to its package name.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately there are no error shown, it simply doesn't compile the external file

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix the issue. Inside the main class when I run the command to compile the Test class, I didn't specified the path for the Robot class (imported by the Test class):

`Process processCompilation = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac -d /Users/faridzouheir/eclipse-workspace/JRobots/src/ /Users/faridzouheir/eclipse-workspace/JRobots/src/zhrfrd/testjrobots/Test.java");`

In order to fix it I simply add it to the command:

`Process processCompilation = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac -d /Users/faridzouheir/eclipse-workspace/JRobots/src/ /Users/faridzouheir/eclipse-workspace/JRobots/src/zhrfrd/testjrobots/Test.java");`